# System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Maximum request length exceeded

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload an mp4 video file that is 5.25 MB in size in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application.

I have tried adding this to the Web.config file which has been the accepted answer in most cases to this problem.

```
<system.web>
    <!-- This will handle requests up to 1024MB (1GB) -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
</system.web>
```

I've also tried setting the timeout as well in the Web.config

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

However, when I go to upload the file I am getting `System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Maximum request length exceeded.`

Maybe there is something that needs to be set in the controller or view?

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        if (fileName != null)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Videos"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Posts", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =  "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

How do you upload video files in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded

Comment: @ta.speot.is "I can find it on google" in no way makes it off topic. Being a duplicate of another SO question makes it closable as a duplicate, however.

Comment: Off topic because of a Google link???  @ta.speot.is how does that make the question off topic

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try add this in web.config (in bytes !):

```
 <system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```